# What is the ballpark GL framerate for iPad and iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, ipad, frame-rate

Does anyone the GL frame rate for iPad and iPhone 4 under the follow conditions:

- Unlit
- Non supersampled
- GLSL texture mapped with two textures.
- Single quad, 4 vertices

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

60fps, if nicely vsynced?

If you're looking for (un-vsynced) big numbers like '1000fps', stop thinking in framerates and start thinking in milliseconds-per-frame. The numbers are a lot more meaningful that way around (You won't panic when your first draw call halves your framerate...)

Comment: Thanks @bluescrn. I'm doing a image visual f/x app. Entirely gesture driven.

Answer (score 3):

According to Apple, iOS devices max out at 60FPS.